# Ordenar subida ficheros php en mi Servidor FTP

Tags: php, ftp

Hola es posible subir ficheros y que el codigo en php me ordene estos ficheros en numeros. Es decir por ejemplo yo subo muchos archivos repetidos, otros no repetidos, y el codigo php me lo va renonmbrando por numeros en orden 1.2.3.4.5.6.... etc y que funcione en varios directorios.
Lo que quiero esque el nombre de los archivos subidos no dependa del usuario sino dependa del servidor FTP. Sino pues tendría que implementarlo en el cliente que sube esos archivos pero al subirlos por medio de FTP puede que sean repetidos y querría a ser posible que el servidor me los vaya ordenando uno luego el siguiente.... así, segun vayan llegando.

Comment: ¿Los ficheros tendrían que mantener el nombre original o podrían tener un nombre cualquiera que el servidor les asignase?

Comment: El servidor le asignase. Esque explico mucho pero no digo exactamente lo que me pasa. Lo que pasa esque quiero implementar un cliente HTTP por lo que me recomiendan usar de servidor FTP. pero este cliente sube ficheros y al mismo tiempo bajaría. Digamos es este caos que no se muy bien como ordenarlo. Y este cliente subira muchos archivos que no estan ordenador aunque se puede ordenar por fecha de llegada. Y bueno podría ordenar a partir de su fecha por orden. Bueno basicamente es eso y seguramente que tenga q hacer un script para las peticiones etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el nombre original del archivo no importa, simplemente puedes guardarlo usando la fecha actual. Por ejemplo:

```
// Obtener información del archivo original (necesitamos conservar la extensión):
$info_archivo = pathinfo('ARCHIVO-SUBIDO-POR-EL-USUARIO.zip');

// Como nuevo nombre usamos la fecha y hora actual, concatenando la extensión:
$nombre_nuevo = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '.' . $info_archivo['extension'];
```

Y $nombre_nuevo quedará algo como:

```
2016-10-12-19-41-01.zip
```

También hay otras opciones, como usar la función `time()` o `uniqid()`.